# Unable to connect to local postgres docker container

Tags: docker, postgresql

I am trying to troubleshoot a connection issue between my postgres client and my postgres docker container (locally).

To start my docker container I ran the following command:

`docker run -d --name postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker  postgres:9.4`

The container successfully starts.

```
➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
14310d9f0ece        postgres:9.4        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgres
```

I then use my psql client which I installed via homebrew to attempt to connect and it simply hangs:

```
➜  ~ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.22
➜ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
// hangs
```

I have also attempted to use pgAdmin to connect which also is unable to connect. There is no log activity in the container that indicates an attempted connection. What is frustrating is that I can successfully ping the container:

```
➜  ~ nc -vz localhost 5432
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif lo0
    src ::1 port 51856
    dst ::1 port 5432
    rank info not available
    TCP aux info available

Connection to localhost port 5432 [tcp/postgresql] succeeded!
```

I also checked to see if anything else could possibly be listening on 5432 but it looks like it is only docker

```
➜  ~ lsof -n -i :5432 | grep LISTEN
com.docke 13037 steve   27u  IPv4 0xd8d4bc5463376f87      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
com.docke 13037 steve  115u  IPv6 0xd8d4bc5462ccdd07      0t0  TCP [::1]:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

Looking for any advice on how else to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK well after spending about a day on this, I came across a github issue in docker where a number of users reported network issues in docker on a mac. I restarted my laptop and now I can connect no problem.

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3350

I am using Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962 on a Mojave Macbook Pro. I will make sure to add myself to the github issue too.